# How to insert .ui form into another .ui form

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

In [Mastering Qt 5 — Page 23](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Qt-5), after creating two `.ui` forms (`mainwindow.ui`, `task.ui`), they give the following instruction:

> Open the MainWindow.ui file and edit it to get the following result:

And show a pic with `mainwindow.ui` now having the `tasksLayout` (which uses `task.ui`) QVBoxLayout added as a child.

They give zero explanation of how to do this. I tried dropping a QVBoxLayout in place, renamed it to `tasksLayout`, and tried a build, but got the error:

> allocation of incomplete type 'Ui::Task', ui(new Ui::Task)

I assume the technique here is to load the subform dynamically in code, as I believe this code does:

```cpp
ui->tasksLayout->addWidget(task);
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

<sup>I'm the co-author of the book "[Mastering Qt 5](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Qt-5)".</sup>

---

- The page 15 to 22 explains how to use the Qt designer with a drag and
  drop off the items. So you should already know how to drag and drop a
  checkbox, label, or a button (and rename it).
- The only new elements of the page 23 are the 2 layout items `toolbarLayout` and `tasksLayout`. The screenshot of the object Inspector shows you the item hierarchy: so you can see that `toolbarLayout` contains the button, spacer, and label. But `tasksLayout` is empty. As other items, the layouts can be drag and drop but will be displayed as a red rectangle. So if you drop a QLabel inside this red rectangle, the label will be "inside" the layout.
- Do not confuse the toolbar creation performed with the Qt Designer explained page 23 and the dynamic Task creation from C++ explained page 24 and 25.

For this simple UI ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zglAK.png)), just follow the hierarchy from top to bottom:

1. Drag and drop a Horizontal layout **INSIDE** the central widget and
   rename it `toolbarLayout`
2. Right-click on the central widget and “lay out vertically”
3. Drag and drop the label, spacer, and button **INSIDE** the
   `toolbarLayout`
4. Drag and drop a Vertical layout **UNDER** the `toolbarLayout` (a blue
   helper line will be displayed) and rename it `tasksLayout`
5. Add a vertical spacer **UNDER** `tasksLayout` (again check the blue helper line)